# Can you seriously have different parameter names but same function?

Tags: javascript

(Sorry for my bad English!!)

It's hard to explain because English is not my primary language but I just wrote this code:

```
function calculateAge(yearBorn){

    return 2020 - yearBorn;
}

var johnAge = calculateAge(1990);
var janeAge = calculateAge(2000);
var stevenAge = calculateAge(1998);

console.log(johnAge, janeAge, stevenAge);

function yearsUntilRetirement(currentAge, name){
    var age = calculateAge(currentAge);

    var retirementYear = 65 - age;

    console.log(name + ' retires in ' + retirementYear + ' years ');
}

yearsUntilRetirement(2000, "Alex");
```

This works absolutely fine and I want to know why!

I have a function that returns age (`function calculateAge(yearBorn)`), and I'm using that function in another function `yearsUntilRetirement`

In the first function, there's only one parameter, and it's `yearBorn`, while on the flip side, even when I'm using the same function but with a different parameter name `calculateAge(currentAge)` instead of `calculateAge(yearBorn)`. This also works!

What's going on?

Can I have different parameter names even if the function is same or what?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  In the code you're showing, which specific operation is producing an unexpected result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: Nothing unexpected is happening here. In your function signature `function calculateAge(yearBorn)` you are defining a function that takes a parameter that you will call `yearBorn` _in the function_. In this line `calculateAge(currentAge)` you are _calling_ the function and passing a variable named `currentAge`. The value of `currentAge` will become the value of `yearBorn` in the body of your function, just as when you called `calculateAge(1990)`, `1990` became the value of `yearBorn`. You can try stepping through with a debugger and examining the values if it helps you to see what's happening.

Comment: The reason why it works is because the name of the parameter doesn't matter. The content of the variable is technically what is be passed to the function.

Comment: I think you confused yourself by choosing a bad name for your parameter. `currentAge` will have the value `2000` because that's how you call `yearsUntilRetirement`, so `calculateAge(currentAge)` is the same as `calculateAge(2000)` which looks fine. Maybe you should call the parameter `year` or something like that instead of `currentAge`.

Comment: Note that this behavior is common across practically all programming languages

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the parameters like boxes, in the end it just gets filled with some value. Either if you pass `1` or you have that `1` inside a variable called `numberOne`, when the function runs it gets the same thing.

As an example, we can have a function called `sum`:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Here are some ways to call it:

```
// Directly using integers
sum(1, 2);

// Using variables;
var firstNumber = 1;
var secondNumber = 2;

sum(firstNumber, secondNumber);
```

In both cases, when you run the function `sum`, the parameters `a` and `b` gets values `1` and `2` respectively. What you name the parameter inside the function doesn't matter nor does it affect the value being passed.

> One thing to keep in mind is that the order of the parameters is what matters. If you call `sum` as `sum(secondNumber, firstNumber)` the values will flip and you won't probably want that. So keep the order in mind when you are calling a function.

Comment: I see, so in short, I can use one function but with a different parameters, right?

Comment: @prettyversatile Yes, that's the main point of functions: making pieces of code *reusable*.

Comment: Exactly, you can see how I did that in the `sum` function. The parameter was defined in the function as `a` but when I call the function I use `firstNumber`. The only thing that matters is the actual order :)

Answer (score 0):

when you create a function you give it a list of parameters:

```
function myFunction(parameter1){



}
```

when you call a function you place any value in the call:

```
myFunction(somevalue)
```

Now tha magic:  somevalue will become parameter1 inside your function.  That's all that's going on

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "Yes" you can call a function every time with a different value of the parameters being different variable names.

```
function dosomething( parameter) {
... do something
}

age = 40 ; dosomething(age);
born = 1200 ; dosomething(born);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed to know! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the following code

```js
function calculateAge(yearBorn){

    return 2020 - yearBorn;
}
```

The name `yearBorn` is just a placeholder. It has no permanence or affect on any code *outside* the function. Nothing else in the program cares what that variable is called inside the function. All they care about is that the function takes one parameter. Whatever value you pass in when you call the function will get "bound" to that parameter and its variable name, so that it *becomes* `yearBorn` while inside the function.